# A person get's a good deed when he recites the quran but what about the person who hears?

Tags: quran, deeds

Everytime you recite a letter from the quran you get a good deed according to this authentic hadith:

> > Aishah r.a reported: Whoever recites a letter from Allah's Book, then he receives the reward from it, and the reward of ten the like of
> > it. I do not say that Alif Lam Mim is a letter, but Alif is a letter,
> > Lam is a letter and Mim is a letter
>
> (At-Tirmidi)

What about the person who listens to the quran? Does he earn a good deed like the person who recites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listening to the Quran is prescribed in Islam, so yes it earns good deeds.

Allah commands listening to the recitation of the Quran:

> وإذا قرئ القرآن فاستمعوا له وأنصتوا لعلكم ترحمون
>
> So when the Qur'an is recited, then listen to it and pay attention that you may receive mercy.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 7:204](https://quran.com/7/204?translations=20)</sup>

The Prophet ﷺ used to listen to the Quran:

> عن عبد الله، رضى الله عنه قال قال لي النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم اقرأ على القرآن ‏‏.‏ قلت آقرأ عليك وعليك أنزل قال‏ إني أحب أن أسمعه من غيري
>
> Abdullah (ibn Mas'ud) said: That the Prophet (ﷺ) said to him, "Recite the Qur'an to me."
>
> Abdullah said, "Shall I recite (the Qur'an) to you while it has been revealed to you?"
>
> He said, "I like to hear it from others."
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5056)</sup>

And the Sahaba and Tabieen used to do the same:

> أن جماعات من السلف كانوا يطلبون من أصحاب القراءة بالأصوات الحسنة أن يقرؤوا وهم يستمعون وهذا متفق على استحبابه
>
> The Salaf used to ask those who recited beautifully to recite the Quran so that they could listen. And this is recommended by agreement.
>
> <sup>— [Tibyaan fi Adaab Hamalat al-Qur’an](https://shamela.ws/book/1969/108)</sup>

Comment: Understood, great answer.

Comment: Nice answer ! I don't know how I missed the Al-A'raaf [204].

Answer (score 1):

> And those who disbelieve say, "Do not listen to this Qur'an and speak noisily during [the recitation of] it that perhaps you will overcome. [ Al Fussilat 41:26 ]

Since a disbeliever will not invite a believer for a good act, hence there is a general ruling that one should listen to Qur'an when it's recited and should not speak noisily so as to disrupt it's recitation. Hence, listening Qur'an may be interpreted as a good deed.